# Undo jQuery function if window size changes

Tags: jquery

I have here this jQuery function:

```js
$("#show-nav").click(function() {
  $("nav").toggle();
});
```

```css
nav {
  display: block;
}

#show-nav {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  nav {
    display: none;
  }
  #show-nav {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="show-nav">Show navigation</div>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Thre</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

This navigation should have a toggle function on small screens. So I worked with `@media screen` and hid it for screen sizes under `700px`.

The Problem: If you hide the navigation in the under `700px` area, and resize then the browser window larger, the navigation is still invisible.

Is there a possibility to undo jQuery actions with resizing the browser window?

Comment: what is your current `@media screen` logic? share that css also.

Comment: Is it okay like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add css code which will always show the navigation if the browser is more than 700px. So you could use the below code:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 701px) {
    nav { display: block !important }
}
```

If you still face issues implementing this. Please edit your question with providing full code along with HTML, CSS and jQuery. I would definitely help further.

Comment: I updated the code. I think your idea would work. But is it really a good option doing it like that?

Comment: It would be best to make things using CSS because it loaded with DOM. You can achieve the same with jQuery but CSS is better than using jQuery to achieve what you need in this case.

Comment: Hm okay. Does a browser calculate the space between one pixel and another? I mean ... what happens if I take your solution, and the browser is 700.5 px wide?

Comment: It won't happen. Browser can be resized +1px or -1px. That's how the whole responsive things works. It should work just find in every case, I have used the same in more than 100 websites. Never face that kind of issue at all. You're good to go without any doubt.